# RESTfull Jersey application error in executable jar

Tags: java, jersey, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I made a simple REST Jersey application starting with maven jersey-quickstart-grizzly archetype (from http://download.java.net/maven/2).

It works fine if I run that with maven command (mvn compile exec:java); but if I made a single executable jar it return the following error:

```
11-nov-2011 10.58.33 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException

GRAVE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A mess
age body writer for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.S
tring, and MIME media type text/plain was not found
```

I try to made the jar with *assembly* and *shade* plugin and in either case I have the same problem.

I've googled a lot and I found many people have the same issue but still not a solution

Comment: I have exactly same problem with Jetty server

Answer (score 5):

You are not correctly merging META-INF/services/* files. Fix that and it will work.

(You need to add content when you are merging two or more jars, not replace. Actual problem is that you don't have "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider" line in your META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader file).

Comment: haahaa, I always look into the wrong file, the file is *javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter* and not *javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader* (in this file there is "com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider"). But why maven doesn' include this string?

Comment: well, you are repackaging some, so you often need to do little "extra". Assembly plugin (as far as I know) by default just unpacks and *replaces* files found in defined set of jars.. Shade plugin should better, see comment to issue JERSEY-440 http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-440 (you might omitted some configuration).

Comment: I replace *jersey-client* with *jersey-bundle* and also *assembly* with *shade* with different trasformer parameyer (like in the examples) but the result is the same (probably I don't understand every thing I do)

Comment: I have same problem with Jetty. In my `MessageBodyReader` I have only `ViewableMessageBodyWriter`. As you pointed out `StringProvider` is missing. Could you say something more about this 'merging'? I am using `-assembly-` too.

Comment: you need to *concatenate* files in META-INF/services dir, not replace (assembly plugin does replace). ServicesResourceTransformer from maven shade plugin should work for you, since it does it properly. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer